# Fail inserting XML into database PHPMyAdmin usin PHP script

Tags: php, mysql, xml, database

I've try to insert the XML document to the database phpmyadmin, i did'nt see any erros, but the table of my database is still on empty.
This is my .xml

```
<item>
<station>
<name id="1" shortname="Car">Chevrolet</name>
<address phone="125469" fax="366155" email="rasziq@gmail.com">
Detroit
</address>
</station>
<station>
<name id="2" shortname="Car">Toyota</name>
<address phone="8548556" fax="666873" email="sanders@yahoo.com">
Alabama
</address>
</station>
</item>
```

this is my database
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REJfw.png)

and this is my php script

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");

$affectedRow = 0;

$xml = simplexml_load_file("stasiun.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");

foreach ($xml->children() as $row) {

    $name = $row->name;
    $address = $row->address;

    $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_tutorials(name, address) VALUES ('" . $name . "','" . $address . "')";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if (! empty($result)) {
        $affectedRow ++;

    } else {
        $error_message = mysqli_error($conn) . "\n";
    }
}

?>
<?php
if ($affectedRow > 0) {
    $message = $affectedRow . " records inserted";
} else {
    $message = "No records inserted";
}

?>
```

Comment: if you `echo` the sql statement in the loop does it look correct?

Comment: You reference `$row->nama` and yet your XML uses `name` (same with `alamat`), also these will be SimpleXMLElements - you need to cast them to strings.  Try `$name = (string)$row->name;` and `$address = (string)$row->address;`